# How to plot a large number of dots on the google map using Bokeh?

Tags: python, google-maps, jupyter, bokeh, large-data

I have a large dataset of latitude and longitude and I want to plot them on google map.
I follow this article to be able to plot them on the map : https://thedatafrog.com/en/articles/show-data-google-map-python/
But in the article it says "As a rule of thumb you can only plot up to 50 000 points" while I have around 9 million points.
my code loos like this :

```
from bokeh.models import GMapOptions
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.io import export_png

def plot_map(lat, lng, zoom=10, map_type='roadmap'):
    gmap_options = GMapOptions(lat=lat, lng=lng, map_type=map_type, zoom=zoom)
    p = gmap(api_key, gmap_options, title='Map', width=bokeh_width, height=bokeh_height)
    
    # definition of the column data source: 
    source = ColumnDataSource(smr_lat_lon)
    # see how we specify the x and y columns as strings, 
    # and how to declare as a source the ColumnDataSource:
    center = p.circle('lon', 'lat', size=4, alpha=0.2, 
                      color='red', source=source)
    show(p)
    export_png(p, filename="plot.png")
    return p
p =  plot_map(lat, lon, map_type='roadmap')
```

When I run the code with 50 000 points it works fine but with all my points the Jupyter workspace freezes.
Any help on how to plot a large number of points on the google map will highly be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Bokeh is intended and designed for interactivity and drill-down, so it sends all the data points. So 9M coordinate pairs is 18M 64-bit floats or ~144MB of raw data to serialize, send, unserialize, and process into *screen coordinate*, which will add another 144MB in memory. This will destroy any browser tab, so a plain Bokeh solution will simply never be workable, full stop. You will have to resort to something like Holoviews+Datashader, which can pre-render millions or billions of points as images that can be sent to Bokeh in an interactive way https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Large_Data.html

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this for me and sending me the link for Holoviews! I will start using this.